# Flowplayer JS API not working because Flowplayer not 'loaded'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, flowplayer

I have several videos autoplaying on a webpage using Flowplayer and jQuery like so:

```
$('.video').each(function (k, obj) {
  $(obj).flowplayer(...)
})
```

They're streaming videos and start playing automatically.

Later I want to use the [Javascript API](http://flowplayer.org/documentation/api/index.html) to interact with the player. It's not working, despite `$f()` returning a Flowplayer object:

```
$f('video1') // -> {_api: function ...}
```

I just learned that you must 'load' the player first, but that doesn't help:

```
$f('video1').isLoaded() // -> false
$f('video1').load(function () { console.log('video loaded') })
$f('video1').isLoaded() // -> false
```

The bizarre thing is that when I call `load()` the video flashes to black and then starts playing again, but the load callback function doesn't fire.

Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

Check your arguments. The load() api method is as follows:

```
load([video],[callback])
```

try something like this:

```
load('path_to_your_video', function(){ ...
```

Hope that fixed it!